# Location of dlls and other files when a VSTO AddIn project is built in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsto

As explained in this [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx), when you run/build an MS Word VSTO project in Visual Studio, it creates your custom office Word AddIn in Word application. You can later remove that AddIn using VS as follows:

**Cleaning up the Project** (quoted from the last section of the above MSDN Tutorial)

```
When you finish developing a project, remove the VSTO Add-in assembly, registry entries, and security settings from your development computer. Otherwise, the VSTO Add-in will continue to run every time that you open Word on your development computer.
To clean up the completed project on your development computer
In Visual Studio, on the Build menu, click Clean Solution.
```

**My Question**: When custom AddIn is created (as explained in the above MSDN tutorial) where are the corresponding dlls, and other related files (data files etc) from AddIn project get deployed?

Answer (score 0):

While building your project in Visual Studio and 'running' the Add-in, Visual Studio, or ClickOnce I should say, deployment stores the installed Add-in in a ClickOnce cache. The quote tries to remind you that you need to clear this 'cache' containing your developer deployments when you want to specifically run your 'production' bits.

To clean this, you can -after setting aside your final built production deployment bits- clean your project using the Visual Studio menu. This will also clear the deployed developer cache (and you will notice that the Add-in entry disappears from your Office application that you targeted)

So much for the  context, the cached ClickOnce files can be found under the folder: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

There will be some directories with what you might feel are named randomly, but that is because they are generated by the system. It is best not to clean these manually, but either use the Clean option in Visual Studio or use a tool called Mage (see thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de8e4a91-d60d-489c-b64b-59440a0293ee/mage-cc?forum=vsto)

Comment: 1. In VS 2015, I clicked on `Rebuild Solution` menu but I don't see any files in `C:\Users\myUSerName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` 2. How do I programmatically get access to this folder?