# VB.NET VSTO Excel Add-In to query an oracle database

Tags: excel, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio, vsto

I created a VSTO Add-In for Excel with Visual Studio. It does a lot of things but the most important one is that it queries an Oracle database.

My problem is that I have to deploy the application to many computers and it seems that the query functions won't work on machines other than mine.

For a simple VB.NET application the trick was I had to copy OracleManagedDataAccess.dll along with my exe. So my question is, in case of VSTO Add-Ins, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try click-once deployment? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213653/832052

Comment: Yea, I use click-once. Deployment is ok for me, other users can install my VSTO and every function seems to work. Only the oracle query function won't work.

Comment: Can you change the property on the dll to Copy Always to output directory?